# How do I convert object to list<String>

Tags: c#, sql-server

I don't know how to convert `object()` to `List<string>` and I am getting errors.

This works but I keep on getting the return `List<string>` as `null` :

```
     public List<string> DspStrg()
     {
        List<string> dspString = new List<string>();

        conn(); //opens connection to database
        StringBuilder dspStrgQuery = new StringBuilder();
        dspStrgQuery.Append("Select String From DisplayToJ");

        OdbcCommand commDspQuery = new OdbcCommand(displayStringQuery.ToString(), oConnection);
        OdbcDataReader RDisplay = commDspQuery.ExecuteReader();

        string[] d ;
        Object doh = new object();
        while(RDisplay.Read() )
        {
            try
            {
                doh = RDisplay[0];
               //-----------
               // convert object to List<string> here

            }
            catch(OdbcException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        RDisplay.Close();
        return dspString;

     }
```

Comment: What is the type of object returned by `RDisplay[0]` ?

Comment: @Sean Check it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: just: List<String> yourList = new List<String>(); yourList.AddRange(d);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything, just add each item to the collection

```
List<string> dspString = new List<string>();
...
while(RDisplay.Read())
{
    try
    {
        dspString.Add(RDisplay.GetString(0));
    }
    catch(OdbcException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```